# Select rows where column is two different values

Tags: sql, database, crystal-reports, db2-400

I have a table like this:

| id | item | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 1 |
| 2 | Apple | 7 |
| 3 | Banana | 5 |
| 4 | Banana | 6 |
| 5 | Pear | 1 |
| 6 | Pineapple | 7 |

How do I only select rows that have both [1,7] as values?

Output:

| id | item | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 1 |
| 2 | Apple | 7 |

Comment: why pineapple is not considered ,it is also having 7 as value??

Comment: I need only rows that satisfy both conditions [1&7]

Answer (score 0):

Edit: You can try using a sub query like this

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE
 WHERE ITEM IN 
 (SELECT ITEM FROM TABLE WHERE VALUE IN (1,2)
 GROUP BY ITEM HAVING COUNT(ITEM) = 2)
```

Comment: When I do this I get answers for Pear and Pineapple as they satisfy one condition but not both

Comment: You need to be more specific and it depends if theres duplicates or not because I dont know if your table is normalized. Can there be two records with Apple 1?

Comment: I think i understand what you're trying to do, see my edit.